# Why the if condition runs the other way

Tags: java, if-statement, null

the value passed from`jsonObject.getString("firstName");` to `firstNameValidateUser` is `null` as it doesn't have any value, I need to run the following code which contain `String firstName=jsonObject.getString("firstName");....` till `returnedUser = new User(firstName, lastName, user.userName, user.password, birthDate, position,qualification,email);` when the value of `firstNameValidateUser` is `null`. How do I check it,I have used the `if` condition to check if the `firstNameValidateUser`is `null` ,but from the output it seems like it is working the other way round. Is there something wrong with my `if` condition, or if I have done any other mistake please notify me.. please help me to fix this. Thank you in advance.

```
firstNameValidateUser=jsonObject.getString("firstName");
// if there are no details are send through the JSON object,
Log.e("jsonObjectlength",jsonObject.length()+"");
Log.e("firstName",firstNameValidateUser);
String usedToCheck=null;
if (firstNameValidateUser!=null && !firstNameValidateUser.isEmpty()) {
    Log.e("firstName","firstName is not null");
    String firstName = jsonObject.getString("firstName");
    String lastName = jsonObject.getString("lastName");
    //String username=jsonObject.getString("username");
    //String password=jsonObject.getString("password");
    String position=jsonObject.getString("position");
    String qualification=jsonObject.getString("qualification");
    String birthDate=jsonObject.getString("birthDate");
    String email=jsonObject.getString("email");
    returnedUser = new User(firstName, lastName, user.userName, user.password, birthDate, position,qualification,email);
    //values are sent to the returnedUser Object
} else {
    Log.e("is Empty","firstName is null");
    returnedUser = null;
}
```

Comment: `firstNameValidateUser==null && !firstNameValidateUser.isEmpty()` , makes no sense if `firstNameValidateUser` is `null` , why would you invoke `isEmpty()` on it.

Comment: Now you changed your code, so your question makes even less sense. If the variable is null, your code goes to the else clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easiest way to check is using native API

```
if (jsonObject.isNull("firstName")) {
    Log.e("is Empty","firstName is null");
} else {
    Log.e("firstName","firstName is not null");
}
```

Refer to android API
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Wrong condition:

Try:

```
if (firstNameValidateUser!=null || !firstNameValidateUser.isEmpty()) {
    // Rest of your code.
}
```

Reason:

```
True && True == True
True && False == False
```

So from 2nd case, if the second value will be False, it won't enter the if condition.

Comment: The condition is correct, firstNameValidateUser!=null is make sure object firstNameValidateUser is not null, then use !firstNameValidateUser.isEmpty() to check the string is not a empty string. If change to your code, the condition will cause NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

So after the code edit it seems fine, however if the error still persists then i suggest you check if the following line actually returns something at all.

```
firstNameValidateUser=jsonObject.getString("firstName");
```

(Just let it show up in the console using:  `console.log()` )
If that returns nothing the problem is probably in the code that either retrieves the string or the code that sets the string.